# PowerShell script that runs in background changing specific process priority to low whenever it is ran

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-1.0

I am trying to deploy a script via our Group Policy that will run in the background and watch for a process called "3dsmax.exe". Each time this process is started, I want to make sure it's priority level is set to "low".

My Powershell understanding is extremely limited.
I tried combining the following using different forums but that does not seem to work and I beleive this will terminate after first occurrence which is not preferable. I use "calc.exe" as a testing process.

```
#requires -version 2.0

Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_ProcessStartTrace -SourceIdentifier processStarted



$prog = 'calc.exe'
$newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier processStarted

If ($progs -match $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.ProcessName)
{ 
    $prog = Get-Process -Name calc
    $prog.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::Low
}
```

Any help would be super:)

Comment: Add a snip to determine the processID (PID) so you can be sure to only affect the correct instance.   or alternatively, loop through all instances of 'calc.exe' and only restart if processpriority is not already Low.

Comment: also my get-process commands only work without the .exe   `$prog = Get-Process -Name calc`

Comment: What OS version are these machines running?

Comment: Clients run Windows 7 Professional x64

Comment: I edited my code to add $prog = 'calc.exe' so that the If statement actually compares against 'calc.exe'. I beleive there could be only one instance of that process running at one given time (to my knowledge). However, it can run multple times in a day ,thats why I want the script to continuously run in the background. Having said that, it's not working, need to do more reading:)

Comment: I understand your question BUT a better solution might be offered if you can indicate the reason why you want to set the priority level to "low"

Comment: Definitely. We have (Autodesk 3Dsmax)backburner program installed, as service, on all workstations in the office. When running, it enables the affected workstation to become a part of a render farm which uses workstations' CPU, RAM for animation rendering - CPU, RAM intensive. Intensive as in, 100% CPU utilization. When a workstation receives the commands to render an animation, it launches a process 3dsmax.exe which consumes the CPU and RAM.

Comment: The problem is, these workstations are used by other people locally during day time to do other tasks. So when 3dsmax.exe kicks in during the day, the workstation becomes unusable for the local user. I would like to bump priority for that 3dsmax.exe down to "low" so the two tasks can coexist without interrupting each other.

Comment: Very good, that helps a lot.
In addition to looking at priority you should also look at CPU affinity - you may be able to start up the service and tie it to just 1 processor - effectively limiting its impact on each machine.

Comment: Thank you. That is a great idea. I actually manually experimented with affinity as well but have no idea how to change that via PowerShell

Comment: Found this: http://digitaljive.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/set-processor-affinity-with-powershell/. May go off that to change affinity as well in addition to priority. While priority is great, i find that people still experience a reasonable amount of lag even though the 3dsmax.exe is set to low (at 100% CPU load).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method.  The "::Low", was not recognized when I tested, had to use ::Idle.  EDIT: added foreach ? | loop to suppress error in case of multiple instances. Added Idle loop to begin of script to catch any pre-existing processes upon open.

```
$prog = Get-Process -Name calc | ?{$_.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::Idle}

    while($true)
    {
        $Query = "select * from __instanceCreationEvent within 1 where targetInstance isa 'win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name = 'calc.exe'"
            $Eventwatcher = New-Object management.managementEventWatcher $Query

            $Event = $Eventwatcher.waitForNextEvent()

            $prog = Get-Process -Name calc | ?{$_.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::Idle}
    }
```

And here is a little .vbs snip to open the app invisibly, so your users don't get a powershell window.

```
command = "powershell.exe -nologo -command C:\IDLER.ps1"
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run command,0
```

Comment: need wrap a loop around it so that it runs continuously throughout the day.

Comment: Thanks so much!This seems to work! How would you recommend having the loop setup in order for this background script to run gracefully and respectfully to other processes. I've read yesterday that's the script itself can start interfering with other processes running if ran constantly.

Comment: Blah, while its working on a workstation if I run it manually, it won't work when i deploy it via Group Policy (machine level). Must be something thats blocking it

Comment: try from a logon script.

Answer (score 0):

Will this be a good way to go about this?
It seems to work, but I am not sure this is a good way of entering an endless loop with the aforementioned concerns.

```
while($true)
{
    $Query = "select * from __instanceCreationEvent within 1 where targetInstance isa 'win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name = 'calc.exe'"
        $Eventwatcher = New-Object management.managementEventWatcher $Query

        $Event = $Eventwatcher.waitForNextEvent()

        $prog = Get-Process -Name calc
        $prog.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::Idle
}
```