# Running a script when you launch a certain Program

Tags: powershell, windows-7, scripting

Is it possible to run a Script when launching a particular file? (Access in this case) If so, is it possible using the windows task scheduler? Also, keep in mind I used powershell to develop the script.

Comment: You could have a script that launches your access file as a part of the script, and that could definitely be done as a scheduled job.

Comment: There's a file on a local machine and a file on the server. Everytime i open the local machine file, i would like to check the server for an updated version of the file and copy it over if it exists.

Comment: I don't really understand why you want it to be a scheduled task then. Just write a script that does a `If((gci \\server\share\file).lastwritetime -lt (gci c:\path\to\file).lastwritetime){copy-item \\server\share\file -destination c:\path\to\file -force;& c:\path\to\file}` and call that script whenever you want to open the DB.

Comment: Ok then, I guess my question really is, how would i attach a powershell script to an exe?

Comment: You can seriously modify the paths in the code I just gave you, and run the script as is to do what you want. Stop thinking that you need the script to run when you launch an EXE, and think of it as the EXE running when you launch the script.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a WMI event watcher.  This snippet waits for calc.exe to be launched, then runs a script to adjust the priority to low.  Afterwords it loops in waiting for the next instance of calc.exe to be spawned.

[PowerShell script that runs in background changing specific process priority to low whenever it is ran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693028/powershell-script-that-runs-in-background-changing-specific-process-priority-to/20694903)

```
$prog = Get-Process -Name calc | ?{$_.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::Idle}

    while($true)
    {
        $Query = "select * from __instanceCreationEvent within 1 where targetInstance isa 'win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name = 'calc.exe'"
            $Eventwatcher = New-Object management.managementEventWatcher $Query

            $Event = $Eventwatcher.waitForNextEvent()

            $prog = Get-Process -Name calc | ?{$_.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::Idle}
    }
```

Additional info.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/08/an-insider-s-guide-to-using-wmi-events-and-powershell.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/01/19/how-can-i-be-notified-when-a-process-begins.aspx

another example.

https://superuser.com/questions/693596/how-to-know-which-service-is-responsible-for-any-exe-running/693601#693601